# Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Tags: php, mysql

I get this
`*Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string*`
 when I am trying to run this query in my PHP-code and I don't understand why.

The query runs when entered from the commandline, but I cant get it to run in PHP. 
Could someone please help me with this?

```
$pickass = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(aid) FROM asset");
$pickassssult = mysql_query($pickass);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why exactly are you running two mysql_query() statements on one another?

You should simply need to do something like this:

```
<?php
    // Set up connection parameters (mysql_connect() for example)

    $query = "SELECT MAX(aid) FROM asset";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // mysql_fetch_array() etc etc...
?>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem and yeah you are right, I only need one mysql_query. I was not paying attention when writing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pickass = "SELECT MAX(aid) FROM asset" ;
$pickassssult = mysql_query($pickass) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you're running "mysql_query", putting the result in `$pickass`, and then run `mysql_query` again on the resultset. `Mysql_query` (in the second line) wants a string, not a resultset. Don't you mean to do a `fetch` there?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to do something like that

```
$pickass = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(aid) FROM asset");
$pickassssult=mysql_result($pickass, 0);
```